# Force to close when run code with Vitamio lib

Tags: android, media-player

```
public class LiveVideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    VideoView videoView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String httpLiveUrl = "http://aj.lsops.net/live/aljazeer_en_high.sdp/playlist.m3u8";

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(httpLiveUrl));
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```

When I run the code, a force close window appears. I'm using Vitamio lib for Media. Any help?

```
03-22 11:23:04.723: D/AndroidRuntime(275): Shutting down VM
03-22 11:23:04.723: W/dalvikvm(275): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{android.liveplayer/android.liveplayer.LiveVideoPlayerActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.VideoView
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.VideoView
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.liveplayer.LiveVideoPlayerActivity.onCreate(LiveVideoPlayerActivity.java:20)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-22 11:23:04.753: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Hi DR.nik 
I have added LogCat. Any Help.

Comment: i have tried your video url and not load in my local player..

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your VideoView in your xml to use the Vitamio video view, so your xml it should be

```
<io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
                                  />
```

Notice the "io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView" instead of just VideoView. That's because your using the custom one by Vitamio and not the normal Android one.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure ?

in `main.xml` ,You have `Videoview` or any other `View`,

you have `<VideoView  android:id="@+id/myVideoView"/>`

and post your `main.xml`

and check this for refrence ... http://r00tsecurity.org/forums/topic/12059-android-videoview-example/

or http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/03/simple-example-using-videoview-to-play.html

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: create new project i think its problem in manifiest file and try with http://r00tsecurity.org/forums/topic/12059-android-videoview-example/

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `Vitamio io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView` instead of Android `android.widget.VideoView`.
2. Also, add this line in `OnCreate()`:

   ```
   if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
       return;
   ```